# how do i fixed this reinforcement learning for luna lander game with TD3_BC

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, offline, openai-gym

I want to use the replay buffer to save the training experience before the lunar_landing mission, but

I am currently encountering this problem and I don’t know how to change it.

The following is the CODE I used to modify the Td3_BC paper, and I want to run it on the lunar lander.

I tried to modify the replay buffer and the state dimension and action dimension, but I am not sure whether my replay buffer is used correctly and I have been stuck unable to actually access the
experience into the replay buffer.

It will be changed to the gymnasium version later.

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN34H.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyIXk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bgB0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8er5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEm7m.png)
```

The error I'm getting is  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtZac.png)

I would greatly appreciate everyone's help

I wish I could know how I should fix it and know where the mistakes need to be made.